# UIScrollView setContentSize doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a really big problem with UIScrollView. To make sure it wasn't my actual project, I created a NEW project, iPhone only, for iOS 6 and 7. I **disabled autolayout**.

1. I created a Tab Bar project
2. I created a view controller,
   embedded it in a navigation controller and connected it as Tab bar
   item #0
3. I put a UIScrollView in my view.
4. I connected the scrollview in the custom UIViewController created for this view.
5. I synthesized my IBOutlet and set the delegate to self. I also
   implemented  delegate in .h

Here is my code (ViewDidLoad):

```
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 20000)];


    NSLog(@"contentSize width %f", self.scrollView.contentSize.width);
    NSLog(@"contentSize height %f", self.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.scrollView.transform));
```

It returns me "contentSize width 20000.000000", "contentSize height 0.000000
" and "[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]". It scrolls left-right where it should scroll up-down

Please help!

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: As stated at the beginning, I disabled it. Screws up too many things in the app

Comment: Don't you mean the log reads 20000 for the height and 0 for the width?

Comment: No, and that's the problem! It only scrolls in the left-right axis, where I want it to scroll in the up-down axis only

Comment: are you developing on xcode 5 ??? there's an option in the attribute inspector, ( Autoresize Subview ), make sure it is not checked, this is only in the new Xcode, i'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but it might :)

Comment: Try to give the frame of the Scroll view in the code..just to be sure

Comment: @Nour1991 Yes I'm on Xcode 5.0.2, I tried disabling Autoresize Subview on my scrollview and on my view inside my view controller, but the NSLog is still 20000 for width and 0 for height.

Comment: mmmmm i don't know buddy what's going on, this is so weird :\
2 more things to try: **A.** try to delete the app from the simulator, clean your project, and then reinstall, and see if anything will change.
**B.** try to create a new project that has only the code in your question, and see if anything changes.
P.S: are you using external libraries ?? like stuff in cocoapods or anything ?!? (( one of them might be causing this weir behaviour, although highly unlikely ))

Comment: No, nothing not standard, and I really tried all this :\

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue until I realized I hadn't set the UIScrollView delegate. Also, if you're using auto layout, you need to wait for the layout to be applied to the UIScrollView. This means you should set the Content Size in "viewDidLayoutSubviews".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get my scrollview to work either, until I read your answer, and set the content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Setting the contentSize property in viewDidLayoutSubviews worked for me.  Had nothing to do with auto layout.

Comment: Oh my gosh. After days of endless searching and messing with all kinds of solutions to no avail, this post was the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

In viewDidLoad method, frame may not be correct, move the code to this method:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Your code

}
```

Comment: Doesn't change a thing, unfortunately.

Comment: Also check for orientation

Comment: What do you mean? My scrollview takes all the space on my ViewController

Comment: Are you sure that self.view is not nil and self.view.frame is correct?

Comment: Yes, I NSLogged it and self.view isn't nil. And I tried [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1500, 20000)]; doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 7):

Use this code. ScrollView setContentSize should be called async in main thread.

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.scrollView.subviews {
           contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                        CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

                        for(UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
                           contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,view.frame);

                           scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. So some suggestions:

1. Make sure you added  to your .h file like so:

   ```
   @interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    }
   ```
2. Try moving this snippet of code to the "viewWillLoad" method:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 20000)];
   }
   ```

Comment: I know right! That's what really frustrating. I tried your way, but viewWillLoad doesn't get called. Never.

Comment: I created a completely NEW project only to test my UIScrollView code (like above). Nothing can be corrupted. Can it be a setting in my .plist that still thinks autolayout it activated? I'm using Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: Did you disable autolayout for all of your view controllers in the storyboard?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean viewWillLoad, try viewWillAppear

Comment: NB there is no "-viewWillAppear" method, only "-viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated".

Comment: I disabled autolayout in the view inspector, which disables autolayout all over the app I think. I tried putting the code inside - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated, didn't work too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: I'm now starting to get desperate about this. Could someone create a new project with only 1 view controller and a UIScrollView that scroll up and down with autolayout disabled? If I can't get your project to work on my computer, I'll know what's up.

Comment: Please try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846351/uiscrollview-contentsize-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var contentRect = CGRect.zero
    for view: UIView in scrollView.subviews {
        if !view.isHidden {
            contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    scrollView.contentSize.width = self.view.frame.width
}
```

Working Swift 3.X code. Converted @Karen Hovhannisyan's answer.