# Create zoomable view in IOS

Tags: ios

I would like to create a zoomable/scrollable flowchart in iOS.  I would like the user to be able to click on any item in the flowchart to take them to other parts of the app.  Does anyone have any good suggestions on how I could create an interactive zoomable view in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Use [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/). It may seem irrelevant, since at the minimum zoom level, you won't be scrolling at all. However, UIScrollView can be optionally enabled to zoom and to set the canvas size equal to the screen size (default).

First drag a UIScrollView onto your view controller. On the attributes sidebar, enable zooming and set the maximum zoom level. By default, scrolling is enabled, and the content size is set to 1.0. [Put a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846417/4967340) inside the UIScrollView, which you can design your flowchart inside, optionally using Auto Layout.