# Color of view which is a subView of scrollView is not appearing when I am usign auto layout?

Tags: ios

I am adding `scrollView` using constraints and it is working right. But it is showing strange behaviour.

**When I am adding frame of `scrollView` as `[SBV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrllView.frame.size.width,1000)];` then its color is `clearColor` always no matter what I am givig to it**.

**Code:**

```
UIScrollView *scrllView=[UIScrollView new];
[scrllView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self.view addSubview:scrllView];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrllView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrllView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];


[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrllView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrllView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];


[scrllView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)];


UIView *SBV=[UIView new];
[SBV setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

[SBV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrllView.frame.size.width,1000)];
[SBV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

[scrllView addSubview:SBV];
```

**When I am adding frame of `view` as `[SBV setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,1000)];` then its color is same as given my me. Gray in this case**

Comment: theres a rule with `UIScrollView` and auto layout, `UIScrollview` needs to be able to calculate its content size, add one subview to the scrollview and add your views inside that and constrain them.

Comment: As I have written in bold that it is working correct except that color that I am giving to it. @cream-corn

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CGRectMake function instead leave the size as it is.  It wont show any strange behaviour.

Comment: `SBV` is the new instance of `UIView`. What will be its size if i will not use cgrectmake method. ?@irudaya and Also If i am removing the cgrectmake . its not showing the color of view again. there must be some another reason

Comment: Then use size classes and try making the layout guidelines instead of using auto layout

Answer (score 0):

Setting content size when using Autolayout does have no effect.

Please refer to this answer - [UIScrollView contentSize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846351/uiscrollview-contentsize-not-working)

Also this - [UIScrollView doesn't use autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints/13548039#13548039)

Comment: My code is working fine except that color thing @dvole